# How to mitigate against Client Dynamic File Inclusion vulnerability detected by Checkmarx scan?

Tags: javascript, html, security, checkmarx

currently I am attempting to fix high level vulnerability which was detected by Checkmarx scan. The warning from checkmarx is as follows:
`The application loads an external library or source code file using append, at line 69 of data\hr\request.html. An attacker might be able to exploit this and cause the application to load arbitrary code. Similarity ID: 456454008`

And here's piece of the code

```
function save() {
var subject = decodeURI(encodeURI(document.getElementById("subject").value));
                    try {
                      var form_data = new FormData(); 
                      form_data.append("file", file_data)
                      form_data.append("type_", type_) 
                      form_data.append("subject", subject) 
}
```

My question is, how do I mitigate against Client Dynamic File Inclusion on checkmarx?
is it enough to simply sanitize the DOM object?

I tried with DOMPurify and expecting the changes will pass Checkmarx scan...

Checkmarx version: V 9.5.4.1000 HF7

Attack vector:
Value > Encode > Decode > Subject > Append > FormData

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution yet? I see this issue raised for me as well

Comment: hi @Reis, I did, instead of using form_data append, I changed my function to populate data inside json object instead. Somehow checkmarx does not like using form_data append

Comment: @aftoru can you give an code example of your solution? You can also add an answer to your question

Comment: @aftoru how did you populate the file inside json data and POST to server as multipart form? When I add the file to to regular js object instead of form data, the encoding is not set and the POST payload has empty property